# aws amplify not serving content-type for wasm

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, rust, webassembly, aws-amplify

I've written a wasm module with wasm-pack in rust. I'm using it as part of a react SPA. I've published the wasm library to npm and everything works fine on my local machine. It also works on an ec2 instance; however when I deploy via aws Amplify, I get the following issue

```
Unexpected error in loadWasm. [Message: Response has unsupported MIME type]
```

The response header includes

```
content-type: text/html
```

for

```
https://master.d3447bi8c4sf9b.amplifyapp.com/ac0bae67a38fb31af71d.module.wasm
```

I've tried to edit the custom header yml a few different ways

```
customHeaders:
  - pattern: '*.wasm'
    headers:
      - key: Content-Type
        value: application/wasm

customHeaders:
  - pattern: '*.wasm'
    headers:
      - key: 'Content-Type'
        value: 'application/wasm'
```

I'm not sure if the wasm is being served from Amplify improperly or what. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also had this. As well as adding the mime type I added wasm to the Amplify "Rewrites and redirects" rules as below

`</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json|wasm)$)([^.]+$)/>`

Comment: I ended up hosting it in s3, but I never would have found this solution! I'll have to circle back around sometime and try this out.

Comment: So glad I answered here - have to fix the same thing again and totally forgot what I did before!

Comment: You should open a github issue! I would love to mark this as accepted but I havent had a chance to try it so I think that would be inappropriate. If someone else can independently verify I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: In fact yesterday I only made the rewrtie/redirect change and not the custom headers and it worked straight away.

Comment: Interesting. One step closer to the WASM future I guess

Comment: This plus the OP's header tips fixed this for me!

Comment: Can someone explain how exactly do I have to add this in amplifies' Rewrites and redirect rules, there are options to add source and target address, where and how exactly this is to be added?

Comment: I would also add the `webp` extension to the rule above